# JAVA ArrayList<Object>

Tags: arraylist, addition, nodes

*Question2:*

I'm confused on `ArrayList<Object>`, please explain to me the following:

I have a class `Node` which has two fields: `data1` and `data2`

```
public class Node {
    private static int data1;
    private static int data2;
 
    public Node(){...}
    public static void setData1(int data);
    public static void getData1();
    public static void setData2(int data);
    public static void getData2();
} // end of class Node
```

And then I have another class called Link.

```
public class Link {
    private ArrayList<Node> linkList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private Node node = new Node();
    ...
    linkList.add(node)
    linkList.get(how to do it here)
} // end of class Link
```

I want to output the `Node` data inside `linkList`.

```
linkList.get(how to do it here)
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or have you tested it, and it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: maybe you need to create an instance of your ArrayList<node>.

Comment: how is it not working, are you getting an exception, or is it silently failing?  Have you tried debugging to see that `linkList.add(nodelist)` is actually being called?  Btw, normal convention for Java is for classnames to start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: it give me exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply forgot to do something like

```
private ArrayList<node> linkList = new ArrayList<node>();
```

Try:

```
public class Link {
    private ArrayList<node> linkList = new ArrayList<node>();
    private node nodelist = new node();
    ...
    linkList.add(nodelist)
} // end of class link
```

**EDIT**

Take a look to the following sample code taken from [here](http://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Esedgwick/ArrayList.html) to understand how to work with `ArrayList<...>`

```
java.util.ArrayList<String>  v = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    v.add( "able" );
    v.add( "baker" );
    v.add( "charlie" );
    v.add( "delta" );

int n = v.size();
for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    System.out.println( v.get( i ) );
```

Comment: furthermore, if i want to output the linklist, i try linkList.get(0) linkList.get(node.getData()) wrong again !!

Comment: i edited the answer. You should accept it if it solves your problem and better open a new one if you have a new question. otherwise it is hard to follow and help for other people if you change your original question to ask something new.

Answer (score 1):

OP solved it by using:

```
linkList.get(0).getData();
```